# MVC4 grid pictures/icons

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I've got a DB of hyperlinks with pictures/icons of those links.  I've got them to display on my view but I want to grid them on the page, three pictures wide.  Does anyone know how I can do this?

This is the code I have to display the links now:

```
<table>
<tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model) {
    <td>
        @Html.ActionImage(@Url.Action("GetImage", new { id = item.pkID }), item.szDescription, null, "ForwardTo", "App", new { szURL = item.szURI })
    </td>
    }
</tr>
```

Comment: Instead of `foreach` use `for` loop and when index modulo n (n is number of items in a row) is 0 add new row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also remove the table formatting, and use client side code (CSS, jQuery) to decide the layout. This has the added advantage of being friendly to devices that desire a responsive layout.

The grids in jQuery mobile are a good example:

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0-rc.1/docs/demos/widgets/grids/

Comment: Thanks; this lead me to the jquery library called masonry which is awesome.